# Calculate indirect effect of 1-1-1 (within-person, multilevel) mediation analyses

Tags: r, multi-level, autocorrelation

I have data from an Experience Sampling Study, which consists of 8140 observations nested in 106 participants. I want to test if there is a mediation, in which I also want to compare the predictors (X1= socialInteraction_tech, X2= socialInteraction_ftf, M = MPEE_int, Y= wellbeing). X1, X2, and M are person-mean centred in order to obtain the within-person effects. To account for the autocorrelation I have fit a model with an ARMA(2,1) structure. We control for time with the variable "obs".

This is the final model including all variables of interest:

```
fit_mainH1xmy <- lme(fixed = wellbeing ~ 1 + obs # Controls 
                    + MPEE_int_centred + socialInteraction_tech_centred + socialInteraction_ftf_centred, 
                    random = ~ 1 + obs | ID, correlation = corARMA(form =  ~ obs | ID, p = 2, q = 1), 
                    data = file, method = "ML", na.action=na.exclude)
summary(fit_mainH1xmy)
```

The mediation is partial, as my predictor X still significantly predicts Y after adding M.
However, I can't find a way to calculate c'(cprime), the indirect effect.
I have found the mlma package, but it looks weird and requires me to do transformations to my data.
I have tried melting the data in a long format and using lmer() to fit the model (following https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch07_2017_Within-PersonMedationWithMLM.html), but lmer() does not let me take into account the moving average (MA-part of the ARMA(2,1) structure).

Does anyone know how I could now obtain the indirect effect?